# Создание asp.net mvc проекта с onion архитектурой

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Изучаю mvc 5 на metanit. Добрался до пункта архитектура приложений. И тут возникло много вопросов.
Изучаю конкретно onion архитектуру и принцип UnitOfWork.
И в связи с этими пунктами у меня появилось несколько вопросов.

Во первых:
В примере на metanit есть вот такой вот конструктор контроллера

```
IBookRepository repo;
IOrder order;
public HomeController(IBookRepository r, IOrder o)
{
    repo = r;
    order = o;
}
```

И если запустить этот код без ninject, тогда вылетит ошибка, что для контроллера отсутствует базовый конструктор без параметров.
И первый вопрос получается в том, как ninject делает так что такой конструктор уже не требуется? Как работает контейнер зависимостей Ninject?

Во вторых:
Если я буду использовать принцип UnitOfWork мне уже не придётся создавать конструктор с параметрами. И получается всё уже работает без Ninject и суть второго вопроса почти похожа на первый. Зачем тогда вообще нужно внедрение зависимостей с помощью Ninject.

В третьих:
В выше приведённом мной коде с metanit
Для того что бы создать репозиторий используется экземпляр интерфейса, но ведь можно вместо этого написать экземпляр самого репозитория а не его интерфейса. Как как раз и делается в примере со следующей главы UnitOfWork

```
private OrderContext db = new OrderContext();
private BookRepository bookRepository;
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

public BookRepository Books
{
    get
    {
        if (bookRepository == null)
            bookRepository = new BookRepository(db);
        return bookRepository;
    }
}
```

В чём разница между этими способами? Я так понимаю в обоих случаях что если мы сразу делаем экземпляр класса репозитория или если мы это делаем через интерфейс? Всё равно создаться экземпляр репозитория?

Comment: Старайтесь оформлять отдельные вопросы отдельными топиками. У вас уже ответ на первый тянет либо на подробное объяснение.

Comment: @AK немного не понял вашего комментария. Мои вопросы не понятные? Или мне просто нужно вопросы разнести на 3 разных вопроса а не все 3 в одном?

Comment: @AK если нужно пояснить что то в вопросе, я объясню. Скажите только что. А если всё понятно если знаете ответ, подскажите пожалуйста. Очень хочу понять, а судя по вашей прошлой активности вы хорошо разбираетесь) Буду ждать ответа от вас, надеюсь знаете.

Comment: @AK а если всё же вопросы чем то не понятны, напишите какие не понятны, я распишу.

Comment: @AK а если вы имеете в виду что ответы на мои вопросы будут объёмными, ответе тогда пожалуйста хотя бы на 1 а я остальные оформлю отдельными топиками, только напишите если это нужно будет.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал первые два оформить разными вопросами (третий "в чём удобство DI и почему нехорошо делать new" тоже можно, но там быстро закроют дубликатом или накидают ссылок на тривиальные статьи с хабра). И ещё порекомендуют книгу Марка Симана Mark Seeman - Dependency injection CSharp

Comment: @AK хорошо сейчас сделаю 2 отдельных вопроса. А по поводу 3. Я немного не это имел в виду. Вот в первом приведённом мной коде нет new. И я так понимаю это хороший стиль. Но я в том же коде могу вместо интерфейса `IBookRepository` использовать сам репозиторий `BookRepository` и так тоже будет работать. Можете объяснить пожалуйста? Я так понял нет разницы создаёшь ты класс репозитория или его интерфейса?

Comment: По третьему пункту вкратце. Когда у вас в коде жестко зашито new и указан класс конкретной реализации -- вы не можете подменить эту реализацию на другую. С DI контейнерами вы можете указывать разные реализации (вместо настоящего репозитория подсунуть фейковый в тот же самый класс контроллера, а не писать ещё один контроллер специально для теста, чтобы указать фейк/стаб) и это очень удобно в тестировании (которым вы видимо не сильно пользуетесь, поэтому вам и неочевидны выгоды DI). Почитайте книгу, вам не хватает системных знаний, эта книга - одна из самых must read для c# программиста

Comment: @AK вот что я имел в виду. Можете по этому поводу подсказать?